# How to make a smooth change when changing style of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript function that changes the height of the navigation bar when it reaches the top and gets smaller when the user scrolls down.

```
function fixIfScrolled() {

    if (window.scrollY == nav.offsetTop) {
        document.getElementById("nav").classList.add("largerNavbar");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nav").classList.remove("largerNavbar");
    }
}

window.onscroll = function() { fixIfScrolled() };
```

So, it basically adds the class when it reaches the very top.

It works, but it changes immediately. I want to make a smooth transition when resizing. How can I do this, and is it possible to do it without jquery?

edit:

CSS

```
#nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

 .largerNavbar {
    height: 150px;
}

#nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Comment: Wheres your css?

Comment: Learn about transitions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions also duplicate

Comment: Also learn how to use transform instead of just height for better FPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using transition for the bar, and use the class not id, because the priority of id is higher than class, so the height style of `largerNavbar` willn't override the id's height style：

```
.nav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
transition: height 0.8s;
-moz-transition:height 0.8s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:height 0.8s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:height 0.8s;
}
```

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.nav');
a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  setTimeout(function() {
      a.classList.add("largerNavbar"); 
  }, 0);
  
})
```

```css
.nav
{
width:100px;
height:50px;
background:blue;
transition:height 1s;
-moz-transition:height 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:height 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:height 1s; /* Opera */
}

.largerNavbar {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="nav"></div>

<div class="para">click the top div.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. It just turns into largerNavbar class when it reaches the top and there is no smooth transition

Comment: and how are we supposed to add the "when on the top" condition if we are trying to use transition?

Comment: Did you define the initial height of the nav？

Comment: i just added the height and tested it, but didnt work.

Comment: Oh, I get it, that the style of  class can't override the styles of id, so, the height of the dom will not change.Just see my example., for two class, the transition will be OK.

Comment: so my goal was to make that kind of change when I reach the top of the page. That is why I used a condition window.scrollY == nav.offsetTop to add a new class with new size. Is there anyway to fulfill this, instead of hover-condition?

Comment: The most important is that you use class `largerNavbar` can't overwrite the height style of the id `#nav`. And I modify the example, have a see.In my example, once you click the div, the `largerNavbar` class will be added to the div. For your project, it's the same, but just modify the click event to your if condition.